# What is community based authentication in SNMP?

Tags: snmp

In SNMP PDU , there is a field with name "community" , how community add security to snmp ? To be more specific , how a snmp agent know that, community string is correct or wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When sending SNMP traps/requests/informs, the field called community is the security that is used for "authentication". In SNMPv2 and SNMPv2C community is the only kind of security that exists. In SNMPv3, privacy and authentication passwords are way more of a good security.

The community adds security because the PDU sent keeps the community with itself. On the other side, the receiver needs to know the community (this is often done by configuration, depending on what you're using). This way, the receiver can identify that the PDU comes from a valid source because the community is the same.